# What does $E[{\bf{x}} {\bf{x}}^{T}]$ mean?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

It's known that $E[{\bf{x}} {\bf{x}}^{T}]={\bf{\mu \mu}}^{T}+{\bf{\Sigma}}$ but I have seen a very similar identity using data points $\bf{x_{n}}$ and $\bf{x_{m}}$ sampled from a multivariate Gaussian distribution:

$$E[{\bf{x_{n}}} {\bf{x_{m}}}^{T}]={\bf{\mu \mu}}^{T}+{\bf{I_{nm}\Sigma}}$$

First question: What does it mean? Usually an expectation refers to a random variable but in this case I'm not sure.

Second question: A [proof](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aTtU8hz6f9WEJ%3awww.jdl.ac.cn/user/hchang/course_staffs/Solution%2520to%2520assignments.pdf%20&hl=en&gl=mx&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjLiMSvFhsUecZlifO95H5HpEAgEq3nBRfP8M0J73fsoT8Z5f8arA5yRvOk6q1FoHvt_ycyaqvL9GgOwBaUxXuQw3fJvSmVtE9Bo73JwvPEm4N7Ufh7qXSvLdGNyAPEHjDyE79o&sig=AHIEtbSdzGG_MDW7XbK-bk6HMneAXKS7jg) I read says that when $n\neq m$, $x_{n}$ and $x_{m}$ are independent. Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are given independent identically distributed gaussian vectors $x_n, n=1,...,$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\Sigma$. So 
$$ \mathbb E [x_n x_m^T] = \mu \mu^T  $$
whenever $n\neq m$ (because they are independent) and 
$$ \mathbb E [x_n x_n^T] = \mu \mu^T + \Sigma. $$
So maybe $I_{nm}$ is the Kroenecker symbol. That would explain it...

Comment: Yes, you're right. The question didn't explicitly say that but definitely makes sense. However, what is the meaning of calculating the expected value of a couple of samples points?

Comment: The sample points are realizations of a random vector from which you can calculate the expectation. It is not the expected value of the sample point you calculate.

Comment: Of course. That's the part that seemed odd. Then it's pretty much the same than calculating the expected value of a random variable because the sample points behave according to such random variable. Is that right?